# How to pass the same states to a component and a page in Next.js?

Tags: state, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and I faces some difficulties when it comes to pass props.

In my homePage (index.js) I've got a component (searchbar) and it collects the inputs from the user in states.
I want to pass theses states infos to a page (Pdrs).

With react I did that to pass props :

```
<Router>
    <Header
    />
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/pdrs/:id">
            <PdrsId />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/pdrs">
            <Pdrs
                setSearchCity={setSearchCity}
                searchCity={searchCity}
                page={page}
                setPage={setPage}
            />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/contact">
            <Contact />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/update">
            <Update />
        </Route>

        {/*keep home page last route*/}
        <Route path="/">
            <Home
                setSearchCity={setSearchCity}
                searchCity={searchCity}
                page={page}
                setPage={setPage}
            />
        </Route>
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
</Router>
```

The searchbar component was imported in the Home page. The states where passed to homePage (see code above) and then passed to the searchbar component.
But with Next.js I don't have this router anymore.
I have a folder "pages" which contains all my pages (=route).
So how can I pass the same states to my component searchbar and my page PDRS ?

Comment: Have a look into [Next.js custom App](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app), which among other things allows you to keep state when navigating pages.

Comment: I allready looked at this page but I'm not sure how to  send props to Component.  I tried  
 `function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {  
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);  

  return <Component {...pageProps} showPopup={showPopup} />;  
}`  
 but it is still undefined on the pages.   
Could you give me an example of how to pass a state to the _app component ?

Comment: `Component` refers to the page component that's being rendered for the given route. Are your page components expecting and handling the `showPopup` prop?

Comment: Another solution would be to use React context by wrapping `<Component>` in a context provider, this way you wouldn't need to send props down to each component and use context instead.

Comment: showPopup is passed to the layout component from the index page. And then passed to header and finally to the component. But the layout is for all the pages.
Like that the pop up works only for the index pages because I declared the state in this page and then passed it to layout.
So I'm looking for a way to access showPopup in all my pages so I can then pass it to their layout.
I just don't know how to pass showPopup to the component in the _app.js file.

Comment: Never mind. I forgot to pass the states on the pages. It works now.